# Binding click and enter two events in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to bind two events using jquery. One is keypress and one is left click event. I'm not able to do that. Here is my code

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").keypress(function (e) {
```

Along with that I want to add a left click event. How do I manage that?

Comment: Use `on()` to bind evens. `$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('keypress click', (function (e) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to bind multiple events by space separated. For getting fired event type you can use **[`event.type`](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/)**

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('keypress click',function (e) {
     if(e.type=='click'){
          //handle click event
     }
});
```

In case you need seperate handlers for them then you can use

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on({
    'keypress': function (e) {
         //kepress event handler
     },'click':function (e) {
         //click event handler
     }
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to find the value for e.button to check whether it has click event

Comment: @Nizam :  use `this.value`

Comment: "this" we haven't defined right. I want to execute my code only if the user has clicked

Comment: @Nizam : I couldn't get you

Comment: if you need to get the event type , then use `e.type`

Answer (score 3):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a space separating the events

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']")
     .on("keypress click", function (e) {
         // Common Event Handler for both the elements
     });
```

If you want to handle both events separately on same element

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']")
    .on('Keypress', function (e) {
        // Keypress Handler
    }).on('click', function (e) {
        // Click Handler
    });
```

Comment: Also, show code to bind events when handlers are different

Comment: @Tushar, what do you mean *when handlers are different *? He wants to bind the same handler to two different events, no?

Comment: As the question is not clear, it's better to go safer side

Comment: I'm not able to find the value for e.button to check whether it has click event

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` method to bind multiple events together

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('keypress click', function (event) {
     alert(event.type);
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to find the value for e.button to check whether it has click event

Comment: @Soosma $(this).val() will return the value of the DOM not the event type. I want to find the event type

Comment: Then use alert( event.type ); I update my answer please check and let me know\

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this, assuming you need different behaviuors for each event is:

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").keypress(function (e) { ... });
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").click(function (e) { ... });
```

Otherwise , you can just do this in order to bind multiple events to the same handler:

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on("click keypress", function(e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer more specific to detect click and keypress too.

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']")
     .on("keypress click", function (e) {
         if (e.type == "click") {
            alert("clicked");
         }
         else{
            alert("Key pressed");
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$('"#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']"').on('keypress click', function() {
    // dosomething
});
```

Or you can even do like this,

```
var myFunction = function() {
   // dosomething
}

$('#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']')
    .keypress(myFunction)
    .click(myFunction)
```

or do like this,

```
$('#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']').bind('keypress click', function(){
//do something
});
```